# iPhone virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, iphone

I would like to run some iPhone applications on my MacBook and be able to use them with the mouse.

Is there some way to run an iPhone emulator via Parallels Desktop or any other virtual machine?

Comment: Wouldn't that likely be something the iphone SDK might handle?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no iPhone emulator besides the one that comes with iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an emulator in the making, just started through Kickstarter: iEmu: an open-source iOS device emulator - http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/cmwdotme/iemu-an-open-source-ios-device-emulator

Comment: It was canceled due to legal concerns. :(

Answer (score 0):

XCode and the iOs SDK come with an iPhone simulator. Of course, you'd need the source code to the programs you want to run to be able to use it.

Comment: ok, so in practice I can not for instance downlodad apps from the app store and run them there? so it does not have a real and completely functional iOS?